# model names that causing errors in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It seems to me that it is possible to break ruby on rails such that neither scaffolding works anymore nor database migration when particular model names are used.

In particular I noticed this when using "Dispatcher" for a model to be created via scaffold. If I created the same object with a different name everything works fine.

Has anybody made similar experiences, or is there a list of names not to be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Official list of reserved words in Rails: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/reservedwords

"dispatcher" is listed under "Other Names Reported to Have Caused Trouble"

Answer (score 2):

Dispatcher is a class defined by Rails under ActionController - so you're hitting a conflict with the Rails class.

In a Rails console:

```
>> Dispatcher
=> ActionController::Dispatcher
```

If you want to use the class name Dispatcher you can namespace it in a Module although it is probably better not to use a name that conflicts with a base Rails class.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is certainly an interesting idea for the future.